# Add menu options to system tray icon with OpenFin

Tags: openfin

I am looking to open a menu for my system tray icon for my OpenFin application. Something like this :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/has7u.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable for now with current version.